# ng-model to append element in dom not as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to take value from inputbox and then dynamicaly append that value in DOM as html element , but ng-model append it as string .

for example ,

```
<p> para </p>
```

this should append as HTML element not string .

**Note :: I tried using ng-model but it render as a String hence i dont see any h1 element tag instead what i see is full "

## Hello

"

Fiddle ::**

http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi987/Z9vN8/

Code ::

```
   <h1>Comment Box</h1>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">Style Title Bar </legend>

        <!-- Height input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Title-Bar Height</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title-Bar Height" class="form-control" ng-model="title_height">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Color input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Title-Bar Color</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title-Bar Color" class="form-control" ng-model="title_bgcolor">
          </div>
        </div>

         <legend class="text-center">Style Box :</legend>

        <!-- Message body -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">Your comment</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="dynamic_comment" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your comment here..." rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Height input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Box Height</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Box Height" class="form-control" ng-model="box_height">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Color input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Box Color</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Box Color" class="form-control" ng-model="box_bgcolor">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Form actions -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"  ng-style="{height:title_height,backgroundColor:title_bgcolor}">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body"  ng-style="{height:box_height,backgroundColor:box_bgcolor}">
          Reading Comment  ::<br/>
          {{dynamic_comment}}
        </div>
    </div>


  </div>



  </div><!-- row closed -->
</div> <!-- Container closed  -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `ngSanitize` (located in `angular-sanitize.js`) and then use `ng-bind-html`, as:

```
<span ng-bind-html="dynamic_comment"></span>
```

The sanitizer will forbid some elements and will complain while you are typing and the HTML content is incomplete (e.g. unclosed tags). You will have to handle this somehow.

Also check out [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and the relevant SCE documentation.

See forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vH447/ (and check the external resources where `angular-sanitize.js` is included).

Comment: thanks !! i will go through the link which u provided . i asked same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357683/render-textbox-input-as-html-element-tag-in-dom-not-as-string?noredirect=1#comment35774319_23357683  . instead of helping and providing link person gav downvote and dint help by giving clue or refence DOC ... Thanks for giving clue so that i can continue climbing angular tree ..